# TYPO3 - 7.2 FLUID Error: file_get_contents() Filename empty

Tags: php, typo3, file-get-contents, fluid, typo3-extensions

I set up an local TYPO3 7.2 environment with xampp.
The installation works fine and everything else too.

At the beginning I installed the FluidTYPO3 site kickstarter distribution because I wanted to work with FLUID there. The distribution created all extensions needed for that (vhs, flux, fluidpages, fluidcontent) and then I created my provider extension with the builder. 
It also created 4 pages or 1 page and 3 subpages. As I wanted to rename them I got the following error/exception:

***PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in F:\xampp\htdocs\src\typo3_src-7.2.0\typo3\sysext\fluid\Classes\View\TemplateView.php line 318***

I tried to var_dump() that in that file but it didn't help. I get the correct path and filename on other modules but not on the "page"-module where the error appeared. I can not rename, delete or edit the pages.
It seems that something is null there, mh.

Later I saw that the extensions were not for my TYPO3 version 7.2, only for 6.2.99 I think. So I deinstalled all extensions and downloaded the development extensions from Github (https://github.com/FluidTYPO3).
I installed them with an error that my version is too high. The extensions are only for 7.1.99. I thought that it would not be a problem and it should work with it anyway.

As I tested it there was the same error again, again and again.

I don't know where the problem is. Everything works fine on 6.x installations.
Could that be a bug or did I forget something?

**PHP Version: 5.6.3 /
TYPO3 Version: 7.2**

Would be very nice if anyone knows about the problem or could help me to solve it. I don't know which information is needed. Feel free to ask if something is needed.

```
 <?php
namespace TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View;

/*                                                                        *
 * This script is backported from the TYPO3 Flow package "TYPO3.Fluid".   *
 *                                                                        *
 * It is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under    *
 * the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License, either version 3   *
 * of the License, or (at your option) any later version.                 *
 *                                                                        *
 * The TYPO3 project - inspiring people to share!                         *
 *                                                                        */

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ControllerContext;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Compatibility\TemplateParserBuilder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Fluid;

/**
 * The main template view. Should be used as view if you want Fluid Templating
 *
 * @api
 */
class TemplateView extends AbstractTemplateView {

    /**
     * Pattern to be resolved for "@templateRoot" in the other patterns.
     * Following placeholders are supported:
     * - "@packageResourcesPath"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templateRootPathPattern = '@packageResourcesPath/Private/Templates';

    /**
     * Pattern to be resolved for "@partialRoot" in the other patterns.
     * Following placeholders are supported:
     * - "@packageResourcesPath"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $partialRootPathPattern = '@packageResourcesPath/Private/Partials';

    /**
     * Pattern to be resolved for "@layoutRoot" in the other patterns.
     * Following placeholders are supported:
     * - "@packageResourcesPath"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $layoutRootPathPattern = '@packageResourcesPath/Private/Layouts';

    /**
     * Path(s) to the template root. If NULL, then $this->templateRootPathPattern will be used.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $templateRootPaths = NULL;

    /**
     * Path(s) to the partial root. If NULL, then $this->partialRootPathPattern will be used.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $partialRootPaths = NULL;

    /**
     * Path(s) to the layout root. If NULL, then $this->layoutRootPathPattern will be used.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $layoutRootPaths = NULL;

    /**
     * File pattern for resolving the template file
     * Following placeholders are supported:
     * - "@templateRoot"
     * - "@partialRoot"
     * - "@layoutRoot"
     * - "@subpackage"
     * - "@action"
     * - "@format"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templatePathAndFilenamePattern = '@templateRoot/@subpackage/@controller/@action.@format';

    /**
     * Directory pattern for global partials. Not part of the public API, should not be changed for now.
     * Following placeholders are supported:
     * - "@templateRoot"
     * - "@partialRoot"
     * - "@layoutRoot"
     * - "@subpackage"
     * - "@partial"
     * - "@format"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $partialPathAndFilenamePattern = '@partialRoot/@subpackage/@partial.@format';

    /**
     * File pattern for resolving the layout
     * Following placeholders are supported:
     * - "@templateRoot"
     * - "@partialRoot"
     * - "@layoutRoot"
     * - "@subpackage"
     * - "@layout"
     * - "@format"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $layoutPathAndFilenamePattern = '@layoutRoot/@layout.@format';

    /**
     * Path and filename of the template file. If set,  overrides the templatePathAndFilenamePattern
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templatePathAndFilename = NULL;

    /**
     * Path and filename of the layout file. If set, overrides the layoutPathAndFilenamePattern
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $layoutPathAndFilename = NULL;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->templateParser = TemplateParserBuilder::build();
        $this->objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $this->setRenderingContext($this->objectManager->get(RenderingContextInterface::class));
    }

    /**
     * Init view
     */
    public function initializeView() {
    }
    // Here, the backporter can insert a constructor method, which is needed for the TYPO3 CMS extension

    /**
     * Sets the path and name of of the template file. Effectively overrides the
     * dynamic resolving of a template file.
     *
     * @param string $templatePathAndFilename Template file path
     * @return void
     * @api
     */
    public function setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename) {
        $this->templatePathAndFilename = $templatePathAndFilename;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the path and name of the layout file. Overrides the dynamic resolving of the layout file.
     *
     * @param string $layoutPathAndFilename Path and filename of the layout file
     * @return void
     * @api
     */
    public function setLayoutPathAndFilename($layoutPathAndFilename) {
        $this->layoutPathAndFilename = $layoutPathAndFilename;
    }

    /**
     * Set the root path to the templates.
     * If set, overrides the one determined from $this->templateRootPathPattern
     *
     * @param string $templateRootPath Root path to the templates. If set, overrides the one determined from $this->templateRootPathPattern
     * @return void
     * @api
     * @see setTemplateRootPaths()
     */
    public function setTemplateRootPath($templateRootPath) {
        $this->setTemplateRootPaths(array($templateRootPath));
    }

    /**
     * Resolves the template root to be used inside other paths.
     *
     * @return array Path(s) to template root directory
     */
    public function getTemplateRootPaths() {
        if ($this->templateRootPaths !== NULL) {
            return $this->templateRootPaths;
        }
        /** @var $actionRequest \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request */
        $actionRequest = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
        return array(str_replace('@packageResourcesPath', ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($actionRequest->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/', $this->templateRootPathPattern));
    }

    /**
     * Set the root path(s) to the templates.
     * If set, overrides the one determined from $this->templateRootPathPattern
     *
     * @param array $templateRootPaths Root path(s) to the templates. If set, overrides the one determined from $this->templateRootPathPattern
     * @return void
     * @api
     */
    public function setTemplateRootPaths(array $templateRootPaths) {
        $this->templateRootPaths = $templateRootPaths;
    }

    /**
     * Set the root path to the partials.
     * If set, overrides the one determined from $this->partialRootPathPattern
     *
     * @param string $partialRootPath Root path to the partials. If set, overrides the one determined from $this->partialRootPathPattern
     * @return void
     * @api
     * @see setPartialRootPaths()
     */
    public function setPartialRootPath($partialRootPath) {
        $this->setPartialRootPaths(array($partialRootPath));
    }

    /**
     * Set the root path(s) to the partials.
     * If set, overrides the one determined from $this->partialRootPathPattern
     *
     * @param array $partialRootPaths Root paths to the partials. If set, overrides the one determined from $this->partialRootPathPattern
     * @return void
     * @api
     */
    public function setPartialRootPaths(array $partialRootPaths) {
        $this->partialRootPaths = $partialRootPaths;
    }

    /**
     * Resolves the partial root to be used inside other paths.
     *
     * @return array Path(s) to partial root directory
     */
    protected function getPartialRootPaths() {
        if ($this->partialRootPaths !== NULL) {
            return $this->partialRootPaths;
        }
        /** @var $actionRequest \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request */
        $actionRequest = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
        return array(str_replace('@packageResourcesPath', ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($actionRequest->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/', $this->partialRootPathPattern));
    }

    /**
     * Set the root path to the layouts.
     * If set, overrides the one determined from $this->layoutRootPathPattern
     *
     * @param string $layoutRootPath Root path to the layouts. If set, overrides the one determined from $this->layoutRootPathPattern
     * @return void
     * @api
     * @see setLayoutRootPaths()
     */
    public function setLayoutRootPath($layoutRootPath) {
        $this->setLayoutRootPaths(array($layoutRootPath));
    }

    /**
     * Set the root path(s) to the layouts.
     * If set, overrides the one determined from $this->layoutRootPathPattern
     *
     * @param array $layoutRootPaths Root path to the layouts. If set, overrides the one determined from $this->layoutRootPathPattern
     * @return void
     * @api
     */
    public function setLayoutRootPaths(array $layoutRootPaths) {
        $this->layoutRootPaths = $layoutRootPaths;
    }

    /**
     * Resolves the layout root to be used inside other paths.
     *
     * @return string Path(s) to layout root directory
     */
    protected function getLayoutRootPaths() {
        if ($this->layoutRootPaths !== NULL) {
            return $this->layoutRootPaths;
        }
        /** @var $actionRequest \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request */
        $actionRequest = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
        return array(str_replace('@packageResourcesPath', ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($actionRequest->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/', $this->layoutRootPathPattern));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a unique identifier for the resolved template file
     * This identifier is based on the template path and last modification date
     *
     * @param string $actionName Name of the action. If NULL, will be taken from request.
     * @return string template identifier
     */
    protected function getTemplateIdentifier($actionName = NULL) {
        $templatePathAndFilename = $this->getTemplatePathAndFilename($actionName);
        if ($actionName === NULL) {
            /** @var $actionRequest \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request */
            $actionRequest = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
            $actionName = $actionRequest->getControllerActionName();
        }
        $prefix = 'action_' . $actionName;
        return $this->createIdentifierForFile($templatePathAndFilename, $prefix);
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the template path and filename for the given action. If $actionName
     * is NULL, looks into the current request.
     *
     * @param string $actionName Name of the action. If NULL, will be taken from request.
     * @return string Full path to template
     * @throws Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException
     */
    protected function getTemplateSource($actionName = NULL) {
        $templatePathAndFilename = $this->getTemplatePathAndFilename($actionName);

        $templateSource = file_get_contents($templatePathAndFilename);

        if ($templateSource === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException('"' . $templatePathAndFilename . '" is not a valid template resource URI.', 1257246929);
        }
        return $templateSource;
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the template path and filename for the given action. If $actionName
     * is NULL, looks into the current request.
     *
     * @param string $actionName Name of the action. If NULL, will be taken from request.
     * @return string Full path to template
     * @throws Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException
     */
    protected function getTemplatePathAndFilename($actionName = NULL) {
        if ($this->templatePathAndFilename !== NULL) {
            return $this->resolveFileNamePath($this->templatePathAndFilename);
        }

        if ($actionName === NULL) {     
            /* @var $actionRequest \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request */
            $actionRequest = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
            $actionName = $actionRequest->getControllerActionName();
        }

        $paths = $this->expandGenericPathPattern($this->templatePathAndFilenamePattern, FALSE, FALSE);
        $possibleFileNames = $this->buildListOfTemplateCandidates($actionName, $paths, '@action');

        foreach ($possibleFileNames as $templatePathAndFilename) {
            if ($this->testFileExistence($templatePathAndFilename)) {
                return $templatePathAndFilename;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException('Template could not be loaded. I tried "' . implode('", "', $possibleFileNames) . '"', 1225709595);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a unique identifier for the resolved layout file.
     * This identifier is based on the template path and last modification date
     *
     * @param string $layoutName The name of the layout
     * @return string layout identifier
     */
    protected function getLayoutIdentifier($layoutName = 'Default') {
        $layoutPathAndFilename = $this->getLayoutPathAndFilename($layoutName);
        $prefix = 'layout_' . $layoutName;
        return $this->createIdentifierForFile($layoutPathAndFilename, $prefix);
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the path and file name of the layout file, based on
     * $this->layoutPathAndFilename and $this->layoutPathAndFilenamePattern.
     *
     * In case a layout has already been set with setLayoutPathAndFilename(),
     * this method returns that path, otherwise a path and filename will be
     * resolved using the layoutPathAndFilenamePattern.
     *
     * @param string $layoutName Name of the layout to use. If none given, use "Default"
     * @return string contents of the layout template
     * @throws Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException
     */
    protected function getLayoutSource($layoutName = 'Default') {
        $layoutPathAndFilename = $this->getLayoutPathAndFilename($layoutName);
        $layoutSource = file_get_contents($layoutPathAndFilename);
        if ($layoutSource === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException('"' . $layoutPathAndFilename . '" is not a valid template resource URI.', 1257246930);
        }
        return $layoutSource;
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the path and file name of the layout file, based on
     * $this->layoutPathAndFilename and $this->layoutPathAndFilenamePattern.
     *
     * In case a layout has already been set with setLayoutPathAndFilename(),
     * this method returns that path, otherwise a path and filename will be
     * resolved using the layoutPathAndFilenamePattern.
     *
     * @param string $layoutName Name of the layout to use. If none given, use "Default"
     * @return string Path and filename of layout files
     * @throws Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException
     */
    protected function getLayoutPathAndFilename($layoutName = 'Default') {
        if ($this->layoutPathAndFilename !== NULL) {
            return $this->resolveFileNamePath($this->layoutPathAndFilename);
        }
        $paths = $this->expandGenericPathPattern($this->layoutPathAndFilenamePattern, TRUE, TRUE);
        $possibleFileNames = $this->buildListOfTemplateCandidates($layoutName, $paths, '@layout');
        foreach ($possibleFileNames as $layoutPathAndFilename) {
            if ($this->testFileExistence($layoutPathAndFilename)) {
                return $layoutPathAndFilename;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException('The layout files "' . implode('", "', $possibleFileNames) . '" could not be loaded.', 1225709596);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a unique identifier for the resolved partial file.
     * This identifier is based on the template path and last modification date
     *
     * @param string $partialName The name of the partial
     * @return string partial identifier
     */
    protected function getPartialIdentifier($partialName) {
        $partialPathAndFilename = $this->getPartialPathAndFilename($partialName);
        $prefix = 'partial_' . $partialName;
        return $this->createIdentifierForFile($partialPathAndFilename, $prefix);
    }

    /**
     * Figures out which partial to use.
     *
     * @param string $partialName The name of the partial
     * @return string contents of the partial template
     * @throws Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException
     */
    protected function getPartialSource($partialName) {
        $partialPathAndFilename = $this->getPartialPathAndFilename($partialName);
        $partialSource = file_get_contents($partialPathAndFilename);
        if ($partialSource === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException('"' . $partialPathAndFilename . '" is not a valid template resource URI.', 1257246931);
        }
        return $partialSource;
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the partial path and filename based on $this->partialPathAndFilenamePattern.
     *
     * @param string $partialName The name of the partial
     * @return string the full path which should be used. The path definitely exists.
     * @throws Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException
     */
    protected function getPartialPathAndFilename($partialName) {
        $paths = $this->expandGenericPathPattern($this->partialPathAndFilenamePattern, TRUE, TRUE);
        $possibleFileNames = $this->buildListOfTemplateCandidates($partialName, $paths, '@partial');
        foreach ($possibleFileNames as $partialPathAndFilename) {
            if ($this->testFileExistence($partialPathAndFilename)) {
                return $partialPathAndFilename;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException('The partial files "' . implode('", "', $possibleFileNames) . '" could not be loaded.', 1225709597);
    }

    /**
     * Builds a list of possible candidates for a given template name
     *
     * @param string $templateName
     * @param array $paths Paths to search in
     * @param string $marker Marker to replace in the $templateName
     * @return array Array of paths to search for the template file
     */
    protected function buildListOfTemplateCandidates($templateName, $paths, $marker) {
        $upperCasedTemplateName = $this->ucFileNameInPath($templateName);
        $possibleFileNames = array();
        foreach ($paths as $partialPathAndFilename) {
            $possibleFileNames[] = $this->resolveFileNamePath(str_replace($marker, $upperCasedTemplateName, $partialPathAndFilename));
            if ($templateName !== $upperCasedTemplateName) {
                $possibleFileNames[] = $this->resolveFileNamePath(str_replace($marker, $templateName, $partialPathAndFilename));
            }
        }
        return $possibleFileNames;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether a template can be resolved for the current request context.
     *
     * @param ControllerContext $controllerContext Controller context which is available inside the view
     * @return bool
     * @api
     */
    public function canRender(ControllerContext $controllerContext) {
        $this->setControllerContext($controllerContext);
        try {
            $this->getTemplateSource();
            return TRUE;
        } catch (Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException $e) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Processes following placeholders inside $pattern:
     *  - "@templateRoot"
     *  - "@partialRoot"
     *  - "@layoutRoot"
     *  - "@subpackage"
     *  - "@controller"
     *  - "@format"
     *
     * This method is used to generate "fallback chains" for file system locations where a certain Partial can reside.
     *
     * If $bubbleControllerAndSubpackage is FALSE and $formatIsOptional is FALSE, then the resulting array will only have one element
     * with all the above placeholders replaced.
     *
     * If you set $bubbleControllerAndSubpackage to TRUE, then you will get an array with potentially many elements:
     * The first element of the array is like above. The second element has the @ controller part set to "" (the empty string)
     * The third element now has the @ controller part again stripped off, and has the last subpackage part stripped off as well.
     * This continues until both "@subpackage" and "@controller" are empty.
     *
     * Example for $bubbleControllerAndSubpackage is TRUE, we have the Tx_MyExtension_MySubPackage_Controller_MyController
     * as Controller Object Name and the current format is "html"
     *
     * If pattern is "@templateRoot/@subpackage/@controller/@action.@format", then the resulting array is:
     *  - "Resources/Private/Templates/MySubPackage/My/@action.html"
     *  - "Resources/Private/Templates/MySubPackage/@action.html"
     *  - "Resources/Private/Templates/@action.html"
     *
     * If you set $formatIsOptional to TRUE, then for any of the above arrays, every element will be duplicated  - once with "@format"
     * replaced by the current request format, and once with ."@format" stripped off.
     *
     * @param string $pattern Pattern to be resolved
     * @param bool $bubbleControllerAndSubpackage if TRUE, then we successively split off parts from "@controller" and "@subpackage" until both are empty.
     * @param bool $formatIsOptional if TRUE, then half of the resulting strings will have ."@format" stripped off, and the other half will have it.
     * @return array unix style paths
     */
    protected function expandGenericPathPattern($pattern, $bubbleControllerAndSubpackage, $formatIsOptional) {
        $paths = array($pattern);
        $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@templateRoot', $this->getTemplateRootPaths());
        $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@partialRoot', $this->getPartialRootPaths());
        $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@layoutRoot', $this->getLayoutRootPaths());

        /** @var $actionRequest \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request */
        $actionRequest = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
        $subpackageKey = $actionRequest->getControllerSubpackageKey();
        $controllerName = $actionRequest->getControllerName();
        if ($subpackageKey !== NULL) {
            if (strpos($subpackageKey, Fluid::NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR) !== FALSE) {
                $namespaceSeparator = Fluid::NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR;
            } else {
                $namespaceSeparator = Fluid::LEGACY_NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR;
            }
            $subpackageKeyParts = explode($namespaceSeparator, $subpackageKey);
        } else {
            $subpackageKeyParts = array();
        }
        if ($bubbleControllerAndSubpackage) {
            $numberOfPathsBeforeSubpackageExpansion = count($paths);
            $numberOfSubpackageParts = count($subpackageKeyParts);
            $subpackageReplacements = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfSubpackageParts; $i++) {
                $subpackageReplacements[] = implode('/', ($i < 0 ? $subpackageKeyParts : array_slice($subpackageKeyParts, $i)));
            }
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@subpackage', $subpackageReplacements);

            for ($i = ($numberOfPathsBeforeSubpackageExpansion - 1) * ($numberOfSubpackageParts + 1); $i >= 0; $i -= ($numberOfSubpackageParts + 1)) {
                array_splice($paths, $i, 0, str_replace('@controller', $controllerName, $paths[$i]));
            }
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@controller', array(''));
        } else {
            $i = $controllerName === NULL ? 0 : -1;
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@subpackage', array(implode('/', $i < 0 ? $subpackageKeyParts :
                array_slice($subpackageKeyParts, $i))));
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@controller', array($controllerName));
        }

        if ($formatIsOptional) {
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '.@format', array('.' . $actionRequest->getFormat(), ''));
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@format', array($actionRequest->getFormat(), ''));
        } else {
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '.@format', array('.' . $actionRequest->getFormat()));
            $this->expandPatterns($paths, '@format', array($actionRequest->getFormat()));
        }
        return array_values(array_unique($paths));
    }

    /**
     * Expands the given $patterns by adding an array element for each $replacement
     * replacing occurrences of $search.
     *
     * @param array $patterns
     * @param string $search
     * @param array $replacements
     * @return void
     */
    protected function expandPatterns(array &$patterns, $search, array $replacements) {
        $patternsWithReplacements = array();
        foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
            foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {
                $patternsWithReplacements[] = GeneralUtility::fixWindowsFilePath(str_replace($search, $replacement, $pattern));
            }
        }
        $patterns = $patternsWithReplacements;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a unique identifier for the given file in the format
     * <PackageKey>_<SubPackageKey>_<ControllerName>_<prefix>_<SHA1>
     * The SH1 hash is a checksum that is based on the file path and last modification date
     *
     * @param string $pathAndFilename
     * @param string $prefix
     * @return string
     */
    protected function createIdentifierForFile($pathAndFilename, $prefix) {
        /** @var $actionRequest \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request */
        $actionRequest = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
        $extensionName = $actionRequest->getControllerExtensionName();
        $subPackageKey = $actionRequest->getControllerSubpackageKey();
        if ($subPackageKey !== NULL) {
            $extensionName .= '_' . $subPackageKey;
        }
        $controllerName = $actionRequest->getControllerName();
        $templateModifiedTimestamp = filemtime($pathAndFilename);
        $templateIdentifier = sprintf('%s_%s_%s_%s', $extensionName, $controllerName, $prefix, sha1($pathAndFilename . '|' . $templateModifiedTimestamp));
        return $templateIdentifier;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper method to make the static call to GeneralUtility mockable in tests
     *
     * @param string $pathAndFilename
     *
     * @return string absolute pathAndFilename
     */
    protected function resolveFileNamePath($pathAndFilename) {
        return GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName(GeneralUtility::fixWindowsFilePath($pathAndFilename), TRUE);
    }

}
```

**$templatePathAndFilename = $this->getTemplatePathAndFilename($actionName);**

This is the bad one in the function "getTemplateSource".

I downgraded the php version to 5.5 (new xampp installation) and it didn't work. :-(

*Hoping for help,
thanks!*

Comment: Could you show us the code around the line mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think the problem is solved.
The problem was that the **column "tx_fluidpages_layout"** of the **table "pages"** **in** the **database** had no entry. It was *NULL*.

Because I could not change and save it in the page properties without calling that error I changed it with phpmyadmin.

To fix that error you have to manually go to the **table "pages"** in the database f.e. with phpmyadmin and then to the **column "tx_fluidpages_layout"**. There you have to **edit the value and change it to** **"fluidpages__fluidpages"**. After that you can save it and reload the backend.

Now you should edit the page properties and set your page layout which comes from your provider extension.

I think it is a bug anyway, that should not happened. In TYPO3 6.x it was inserted automatically.